# How to detect a scan on a local machine?

Tags: network, network-scanners

Is there any way to detect a scan on the local machine ( the pc  that I'm using with a linux os -ubuntu-) from the network that I'm connected to?

I know that for the webservers we could check the apache log for some details that could notify the admin about some unseal behavior but for the   this case where there isn't any webserver or a shared network service that I could follow its logs how can I find out if there is anyone who is scanning the device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Scanlogd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/scanlogd.8.html)* should be what you are looking for. However, this is TCP oriented.

> scanlogd detects port scans and writes one line per scan via the
>   syslog(3) mechanism. If a source address sends multiple packets to
>   different ports in a short time, the event will be logged.

For most NMap scans Snort and p0f are both capable IDS. [How to Detect NMAP Scan Using Snort](http://www.hackingarticles.in/detect-nmap-scan-using-snort/) is a guide about configuring Snort to detect: `nmap -sP -p 22 192.168.1.105` among other scans.

> Ping Scan [-sP] This scan type lists the hosts within the specified
>   range that responded to a ping. It allows you to detect which
>   computers are online, rather than which ports are open. Four methods
>   exist within Nmap for ping sweeping.
>
> The first method sends an ICMP ECHO REQUEST (ping request) packet to
>   the destination system. If an ICMP ECHO REPLY is received, the system
>   is up, and ICMP packets are not blocked. If there is no response to
>   the ICMP ping, Nmap will try a "TCP Ping", to determine whether ICMP
>   is blocked, or if the host is really not online.
>
> A TCP Ping sends either a SYN or an ACK packet to any port (80 is the
>   default) on the remote system. If RST, or a SYN/ACK, is returned, then
>   the remote system is online. If the remote system does not respond,
>   either it is offline, or the chosen port is filtered, and thus not
>   responding to anything.
>
> When you run an Nmap ping scan as root, the default is to use the ICMP
>   and ACK methods. Non-root users will use the connect() method, which
>   attempts to connect to a machine, waiting for a response, and tearing
>   down the connection as soon as it has been established (similar to the
>   SYN/ACK method for root users, but this one establishes a full TCP
>   connection!)
>
> The ICMP scan type can be disabled by setting -P0 (that is, zero, not
>   uppercase o).
>   [Source](https://nmap.org/bennieston-tutorial/)

[What's the most effective way to detect nmap scans](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166734/whats-the-most-effective-way-to-detect-nmap-scans) speaks about this further.

Comment: What abut the others scan types used in Nmap? is there any other tools that I can use to detect them ?

Comment: I have amended the post to include IDS for NMap.

Comment: @UserXD Worth noting, there are different ways to scan a network which generate different levels of "heat."  Louder approaches, such as NMap are easy to detect.  Quiet approaches are much harder, and detecting them may lead to more false positives.

Comment: @CortAmmon would you mind explain more you idea? or help me to find some references for this ? thanks.

Comment: @UserXD If I hit you with a massive nmap sweep from a high bandwidth location, you'll see a whole bunch of activity and say "Dang, that's a lot of activity, and it looks almost exactly like an nmap sweep.  I bet I'm being port swept."  On the other hand, if I use a botnet to probe your machine randomly, roughly 1 port per hour, it will be very hard to distinguish this from noise and other sources.  Also, if two people are doing this, it will be very difficult to tell them apart.

Comment: @CortAmmon I've a small network with some 40 devices, connected and I've some users that I can't trust, it's a public network ( a shared working space) and I'm trying to find out a way to detect any abnormal behave. The last time one the computers was infected with a malware and the only thing that triggers an alert was the access to a shared resources while no one was using it.

Comment: @UserXD "Any abnormal behavior" is impossible to detect, from an information-theoretic perspective.  However, you can generally expect malware to be rather loud in its searches for new machines to infect, so the tools which detect nmap port scans are likely to detect the actions of malware.  It's the pesky APT's that may try quiet low-heat approaches.